# How to change filter column location in ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I use ui-grid in my project.

I need to move filtering field abovse ui-grid,like that:

[image]

Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you need to write the filter by yourself. It's not that hard and there's a [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/321_singleFilter) on ui-grid.info.

What you're gonna do is create a loop that will go through all the rows and change the flag `row.visible` for any row that is matching/not matching the filter.

[FOLLOW-UP] In case you needed more than one column you simply should think your logic considering any possible combination of all filters.

If I remember correctly, in ui-grid they have nested loops, at first they cycle through all filters, then through all rows and if a row is refused by any filter, than it's visibility is cleared (set to false); otherwise, if all filter accept a row, it's visibility is set to true.

Comment: imbalind ,what if I want to create multiple filters.For example,I want to filter by Name and then to filter by Company?